# Changing how conda activate/deactivate updates $PS1

Tags: bash, anaconda, conda

I recently updated conda to 22.9.0

When I do conda activate envname my prompt now looks like:

```
(envname)
```

instead of

```
(envname)[user@host cwd]$
```

What should I do for $PS1 to be set like below after a call to conda activate/deactivate?

```
PS1="($(basename "$CONDA_PREFIX"))[\u@\h \W]\\$ "
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Following the discussion [here](https://github.com/conda/conda/issues/11885), try running `conda init bash` then restarting the shell.